# Child Form Auto Scrolls to the bottom in parent

Tags: c#, winforms

[image: A form with a TabPage containing a child form]

Hi, I have a form with a TabPage, in this TabPage there is a child form displayed, this child form has AutoScroll set to true, however when this form is loaded it is automatically scrolled to the bottom. How do I go about loading the child form scrolled to the top?

Comment: The screenshot doesn't help to see whether it is the form or the tabpage that displays the scrollbar and which control has the focus.  But a somewhat reasonable guess is that the form is embedded with Dock=Fill and that you need to go back to the form design and pay attention to the TabIndex property of its controls.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed by using Hans Passant answer, the scroll position was affected by the TabIndex property.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Set the [AutoScrollPosition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.scrollablecontrol.autoscrollposition?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) of the scrollable form to 0 after everything has been loaded.

```
Form1.AutoScrollPosition = new Point(0, 0);
```